# C++ only implementation of template class

Tags: c++, templates

**I do not have access to c++11 for this project.**

I have a C++ class; lets call it Bar, it looks something like this:

Header FooBar.h:

```
#include "Fancy.h" // <--- Dependency
namespace Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    class Bar : public Fancy::FancyClass<T, ALLOCATER<HARD_CODED_VALUE>>
    {
    };
}
```

Cpp:

None

Fancy is a lib that is being statically linked into a dll. The problem is that when other projects want to use the dll they include "FooBar.h" it says that it cannot find "Fancy.h"

Basically I want projects that include the dll to be able to use this class without needing any additional libraries or headers.

My solution was to just put it in a cpp and have no header file. Unfortintly nothing can find it then? I have tried creating a blank header file that did not work either.

I tried to forward declare it in the header but to do that I need the .h to understand what FancyClass is. I have also tried

```
namespace Fancy
{
    class FancyClass;
    class ALLOCATER;
}

namespace Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    class Bar : public Fancy::FancyClass<T, ALLOCATER<HARD_CODED_VALUE>>;
}
```

in the header. But that causes many errors.

Comment: Pretty much your only options is to add the library include path to the search path or use something like the PIMPL pattern. Choose your poison I guess.

Comment: Can you restrict to some T only ?

Comment: You can't. Your Bar depends on Fancy depending on user-provided argument T, so user needs to see Fancy::FancyClass definition. No pimpl can help here.

Comment: No the T has to be any class. Its a container.

Comment: Could someone explain why this is not possible? If my dll is exporting this functionality why can other projects not use it? Is it because it needs to generate additional templates for the new projects classes?

Comment: "I have a C++ class; lets call it Bar" -- no. Bar is a **template**, not a class. It's a pattern for making classes. `Bar<int>` is a class.

Comment: @marsh There's [loads of material](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dexporting%20templates%20from%20dll) to research before asking.

Comment: You do not have to specify the inheritance relationship between `Bar` and its parent classes in the header file for forward declarations. You only need to say that the (templated) class exists and what parameters the template takes. (ie. `namespace Foo{ template<typename T> class Bar; }`)

Comment: @callyalater I get 'uses undefined class' for the classes used in the new project. I am guessing because it never generated the Bar<Class> for that class?

Comment: @marsh Does the NICE_ALLOCATER class take in a template parameter?

Comment: Ah, yes it does. My mistake. But I have hardcoded that T value in my inheritance.

Comment: @marsh Are you including the namespace as part of the declaration in the template type? Do you include the proper files at the top?

Comment: I believe I am. It works if its all in the header so everything should be setup right. This is a existing codebase.

Comment: Based solely on what you have given us, I can't determine for sure what the issue is. If you have a link to your repo, that would help better understand the include structure. Also, dll's are *dynamically* linked, not *statically* linked. Second, are you specifying the include directory in your compilation command?

Comment: I am building a dll that is statically linking a lib file. Then another exe project is using the dll. What do you mean include directory in your compilation command? I am using visual studio.

Comment: When doing an include, the compiler needs to know what directories to look in to find the header file. If the library you are linking against/compiling with doesn't have an "include" folder, that will be your biggest problem because it will have no idea which classes exist in your library. It needs an include path to know where to find the "Fancy.h" file.

Comment: The dll is building correctly. It is the other projects that are having errors creating these template objects. The whole point of this is that I do not want to include "Fancy.h". Like I said I have it all working with it just implemented in the header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104213/discussion-between-marsh-and-callyalater).

Comment: What if I wanted to use that class internally in my DLL but did not want anyone using it outside of it. How do I make it accessible to the DLL only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you *must* include the header in your executable file in order to use the provided library.

Long(er) answer, the compiler needs to know the structure of the class defined in the library.

Imagine that there is a class called `MyAwesomeClass` that is part of a library you want to use in your executable. The compiler doesn't know anything about that class when you say `MyAwesomeClass awesome;`. How big is it? What methods can you call on it? Does it inherit from anything?

This information is contained in the header file where the class is declared.

```
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    private:
        std::string _name;
    public:
        MyAwesomeClass();
        MyAwesomeClass(const std::string& name);
        void print_name();
};
```

The implementation is defined in the DLL or static library, but when using the type `MyAwesomeClass`, the compiler needs to know at least its structure. Without including the header, the compiler will complain that it doesn't know what type `MyAwesomeClass` is (ie. `undefined class` errors).